# Graphics.fill(Shape) without rastering

Tags: java, swing, graphics, printing

I'm printing a swing component to a variety of printers. One of these printers has big problems with alpha channels. If anything on screen has an alpha channel, the resulting spool size is huge. For the most part, I've eliminated alpha channels. However, there's an element which uses `Graphics2d.fill(Shape)` to fill a shape with some hashed lines, so you can see what's behind the hashes. Is there a way to achieve this without rastering alpha information to the Graphics object during printing?

I believe the printer would be happier if the hashed lines were generated using calls to `Graphics.drawLine()`, instead of `fill(Shape)`, but the shape I'm filling is very complicated (it's a line chart). Is there a way to fill the Shape with drawn lines, which would make the printer happier? It seems like all the Paint implementation are inherently raster-based.

Barring that, is there a way to tell the image to be either fully transparent or not at all? Would that help with the spool size on the printer?

Here's code that fills a circle with vertical hashed lines, allowing the horizontal hashed lines to show through.

```
public class BufferedImagePrint extends JComponent implements Runnable, Printable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BufferedImagePrint());
    }

    public void run() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(128, 128));
        final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(this, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, null, new Object[]{
                "Print",
                "Cancel"});
        final JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Painting Transparent Image");
        dialog.setResizable(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        if ("Print".equals(optionPane.getValue())) {
            doPrint();
        }
    }

    private void doPrint() {
        try {
            final PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            printerJob.setPrintable(this);
            if(printerJob.printDialog()) {
            printerJob.print();
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        // draw horizontal lines
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i=0; i<getWidth(); i+=3) {
            g.drawLine(0, i, getWidth(), i);
        }

        final BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
        final Graphics2D textureGraphics = img.createGraphics();
        textureGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i=0; i<32; i+=4) {
            textureGraphics.drawLine(i, 0, i, 32);
        }
        textureGraphics.dispose();
        final TexturePaint paint = new TexturePaint(img, new Rectangle(32, 32));
        ((Graphics2D)g).setPaint(paint);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(),  getHeight());
    }

    public int print(final Graphics graphics, final PageFormat pageFormat, final int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
        if (pageIndex == 0) {
            paintComponent(graphics);
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        } else {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, the above is as short as I could make the sample code. Well, I probably didn't need printing support. But how can I fill the oval with the vertical lines without sending a transparent raster to the graphics object?

Comment: I did not recommend to post 'sample code', but an SSCCE.  What was posted is ***not*** an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

Could you paint shape to a temporary Image then paint the image (instead of the shape) to the printer?

Comment: Any transparent images I paint cause the spool size to balloon up to the gigabyte range.

Comment: Have you tried painting images with alpha as opposed to drawing with alpha? There may be a strange difference in the way these are handled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered drawing a hash-lines using the complicated shape as a clip?